# How to write ant script in Linux for vagrant up

Tags: ant, vagrant

I try to write a ant script for vagrant up, but for some reason it only get the vagrant command without the up parameter, I write it this way

```
<arg line="-c vagrant up" />
```

can someone help me understand why it doesn't get the up command and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting each word into a separate `arg`:

```
<arg value="-c"/>
<arg value="vagrant"/>
<arg value="up"/>
```

That often works better than the `line` variant.

See [Command-line Arguments](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg) in the Ant Manual:

> It is highly recommended to avoid the `line` version when possible.
>   Ant will try to split the command line in a way similar to what a
>   (Unix) shell would do, but may create something that is very different
>   from what you expect under some circumstances.

Comment: I try it but without success do you have another suggestion?

Comment: I suggest you update the question with more details - e.g. the whole Ant target you're making and the error output you see when you run it.